# Firebase is throwing continuous errors when the device goes offline

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Firebase is throwing continuous errors when the app goes offline. I don't know where the errors are coming from so I can catch them.

The errors stop when the user comes back online.
I am using listeners to listen to Firebase firestore collections and documents.

This is the error:

```
V/NativeCrypto(26596): Read error: ssl=0xb4000074b15e4318: I/O error during system call, Software caused connection abort
V/NativeCrypto(26596): Write error: ssl=0xb4000074b15e4318: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
W/ManagedChannelImpl(26596): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
D/TrafficStats(26596): tagSocket(3) with statsTag=0xffffffff, statsUid=-1
W/ManagedChannelImpl(26596): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
W/Firestore(26596): (24.9.1) [WatchStream]: (9f3395b) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=End of stream or IOException, cause=null}.
V/NativeCrypto(26596): SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0xb4000074b15e4318: I/O error during system call, Success
W/Firestore(26596): (24.9.1) [WatchStream]: (9f3395b) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
W/Firestore(26596): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:124)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:631)
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
W/Firestore(26596):     ... 5 more
W/Firestore(26596): }.
```

After that, the error keeps repeating like:

```
W/ManagedChannelImpl(26596): [{0}] Failed to resolve name. status={1}
W/Firestore(26596): (24.9.1) [WatchStream]: (9f3395b) Stream closed with status: Status{code=UNAVAILABLE, description=Unable to resolve host firestore.googleapis.com, cause=java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:223)
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.doResolve(DnsNameResolver.java:282)
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$Resolve.run(DnsNameResolver.java:318)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
W/Firestore(26596): Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firestore.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupHostByName(Inet6AddressImpl.java:124)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:103)
W/Firestore(26596):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1152)
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver$JdkAddressResolver.resolveAddress(DnsNameResolver.java:631)
W/Firestore(26596):     at io.grpc.internal.DnsNameResolver.resolveAddresses(DnsNameResolver.java:219)
W/Firestore(26596):     ... 5 more
W/Firestore(26596): }.
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

These are not errors you can catch, and the Firestore SDK does not consider it to be an "error" to be offline.  Being offline is just a condition that it handles for you.

The Firestore SDK on all platforms automatically [falls back to the local persistence layer while offline](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline), and tries to reconnect while the app is running so that you can transition seamlessly back to the online service.

Answer (score 0):

To stop the continuous errors, you have to cancel any listeners you have active on a Firestore collection or document.

I created a Cubit that keeps track of whether the user is connected to the internet with the [connectivity_plus plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus).
Then I listened to the cubit in the cubit that contains the listener and based on the online state, I cancel or reconnect the listener.

Now, the error is only thrown the first time before the listener is cancelled.

Here is the code for the connectivity cubit:

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:connectivity_plus/connectivity_plus.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';

class OnlineStatusManager extends Cubit<ConnectivityResult> {
  OnlineStatusManager() : super(ConnectivityResult.none) {
    _statusSubscription = Connectivity()
        .onConnectivityChanged
        .listen((ConnectivityResult result) {
      emit(result);
    });
  }

  bool get isOnline => state != ConnectivityResult.none;

  late final StreamSubscription _statusSubscription;

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    await _statusSubscription.cancel();
    return super.close();
  }
}
```

Here is how I used it:

```dart
class UserManager extends Cubit<UserData?> {

  StreamSubscription? _sourceSubscription;
  late final StreamSubscription<ConnectivityResult> _onlineStatusSubscription;

  UserManager() : super(null) {
    // The listener does not trigger on connection. Only on changes.
    // So it is necessary to set the initial value
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      if (locator<OnlineStatusManager>().isOnline) {
        _sourceSubscription = _source.changes().listen(_apiChangesListener);
      }
    }

    _onlineStatusSubscription =
        locator<OnlineStatusManager>().stream.listen(_onlineStatusListener);
  }

  void _resetRemoteListener() {
    if (FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser != null) {
      _sourceSubscription = _source.changes().listen(_apiChangesListener);
    }
  }

  void _onlineStatusListener(ConnectivityResult result) {
    if (result == ConnectivityResult.none) {
      _sourceSubscription?.cancel();
    } else {
      _resetRemoteListener();
      print('=========== Reconnected listeners +============== ');
    }
  }

  void _apiChangesListener(DocumentSnapshot newUser) {
    if (newUser.exists) {
      cacheUser(UserData.fromMap((newUser.data()! as Map).cast()));
    } else {
      _local.deleteUser();
      emit(null);
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() async {
    await _sourceSubscription?.cancel();
    await _onlineStatusSubscription.cancel();
    super.close();
  }

}
```